# Listening to YouTube links using intent filter

Tags: android, android-intent, youtube, intentfilter

I am trying to make my app listen for YouTube links much like how how YouTube app does. I have an activity with the following intent filter:

```
<activity android:name=".YoutubeLinkActivity" android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                <data android:scheme="http" android:host="youtube.com"/>    
            </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

However, the app that opens up is the default YouTube app rather than mine. I tried the same intent filter for other `host`, too. In that case, the browser just goes to the next page rather than firing up my app.

What needs to change here?

Comment: Use the [App Browser app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.japanesecrackers.appbrowser) to examine the manifest of the YouTube app and see where you differ.

Answer (score 1):

I faced similar issue and interestingly it was working fine in Android 2.3.7.

To make it run on JB and above, I added `android:pathPrefix=""` to my `<data>` tag. So my `<intent-filter>` looked like:

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>

    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>

    <data
        android:host="android.app.myWeb.pk"
        android:pathPrefix=""
        android:scheme="http"/>
    <data
        android:host="android.app.myWeb.pk"
        android:pathPrefix=""
        android:scheme="https"/>
</intent-filter>
```

Comment: @LittleChild if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.